# Open ports for an interface without adding the interface to a zone?

Tags: centos, port-forwarding, firewalld

I am using CentOS 8 and the firewall it comes with. I would like to open a port for my VPN interface (tun0). Is it possible to do this without adding the interface to a zone and then open the port for that zone? I just want to open it directly for that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalld is a zone-based firewall. All interfaces are part of some zone. If this is not explicitly defined, then the interface is added to the default zone. This is initially the 'public' zone which only allows selected incoming connections.

From [documentation on the default zone](https://firewalld.org/documentation/zone/default-zone.html).

> The default zone is the zone that is used for everything that is not
> explicitly bound/assigned to another zone. That means that if there is
> no zone assigned to a connection, interface or source, only the
> default zone is used.

You can change the default zone or you can add the interface to a specific zone. You can also define your own zones. For these tasks, see the RHEL 8 documentation: [Working with firewalld zones](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking#working-with-firewalld-zones_using-and-configuring-firewalld)